# Unable to add a printer through powershell ISE or VScode

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write up a printer mapper for my site and am getting an error when trying to use add-printer in both the powershell ISE and VScode.

```
add-printer -connectionname '\\$printserver\$printer'

  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 | The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is
 | invalid.  Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters.
```

However, when I run the same line of code in powershell, it works without an error and adds the printer to my computer.  I am running powershell 7.2, so version difference isn't a thing.  Entering in the line of code into both the ISE and VScode powershell terminals also work fine, so it appears to be just an issue when I am trying to get the script to run.  The error happens regardless of whether I user variables or hardcoding the print server and printer name in the script.

Comment: What's in your variables?

Comment: my print server hostname and the printer's hostname.  However even if I try it without the variables, I get the same error message.  It seems that when trying to make the script run outside of the powershell terminal it doesn't like \

so, \\printerserver01\pg-53001  for example